# Firestore How to retrieve subcollection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on App that uses Firestore please see the following pic how I organize the data

[image]

I am trying to get data using the following code

```
let db = admin.firestore();

async function getMenu() {
  let query = await db.collection('menu').orderBy("order", "asc").get();

  const snapshot = query.docs;
  snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.id, '->', doc.data());
});
}

getMenu();
```

Output:

```
Feedings -> { order: 1 }

Diapers -> { order: 2 }
```

Can't able to get subcollection

Diapers & Wipes -> Disposable Diapers

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to get data from a subcollection using a query for a top-level collection.  When you query menu, it will only ever give you document immediately within that collection.  In this respect, Firestore queries are said to be "shallow".

If you want documents from a subcollection, you will need to make another query that targets that specific subcollection.  For example:

```
db.collection("menu").doc("Diapers").collection("Diapers & Wipes").get()
```